# How to estimate the weight of quarry material in a pile

Tags: computer-vision, ai-design

A quarry wants to know the weight of materials they extract from the quarry. I was thinking they could use some computer vision to estimate the weight based on a 3D generated model of the quarry material.

I have considered using a weigh bridge mechanism, where the quarry material is loaded into a truck and weighed, but this is too costly to construct and implement.

Is there a good 3D model generator that can be used for the task? Or is there a better method for estimating the weight?